# skim function: problem caused by dplyr::summarize and purr:: map2

Tags: r

I run into this problem and I dont know how to solve it.
Can someone help me? I am trying to skim my data frame.

df %>% skim()

Error in `dplyr::summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `skimmed = purrr::map2(...)`.
Caused by error in `dplyr::summarize()`:
! Can't transform a data frame with duplicate names.

Comment: Does your data frame have duplicate names, ie multiple columns that can't be distinguished by name alone? If you have the janitor package installed, you might try `df %>% janitor::clean_names() %>% skim()`

Comment: I tried this and i get: Error in clean_names.default(.) : 
  No `clean_names()` method exists for the class function
Consider janitor::make_clean_names() for other cases of manipulating vectors of names.

Comment: It sounds like you have defined `df` as a function instead of a data frame. Maybe you used `df()`?

Comment: The problem is that I imported a sav file into R and it always causes problems. I exported the df as csv and re-imported it and all my functions seem to work. Thank you for your help